# When compile PHP extension, How does the compiler know WHERE the defintion of standard builtin function(e.g. base64_encode) is

Tags: php, php-extension

I wrote a PHP extension, which called a standard builtin function, `php_base64_encode()`, like

```
#include "ext/standard/base64.h"

PHP_FUNCTION(foo_bar) {
    char *arg = NULL;
    size_t arg_len;
    zend_string *strg;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "s", &arg, &arg_len) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    // do something

    strg = php_base64_encode("hello", strlen("hello"));
    RETURN_STR(strg);
}
```

I have already known that the `Makefile` contains `INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/include/php ...`, so the compiler will know where `ext/standard/base64.h` is. However, I'm wordering how does the compiler know WHERE the defintion of `php_base64_encode()` is.

Comment: All the helper classes and functionalities have been loaded at the time of bootstrapping process. So when you are using any helper function it automatically check the definition for that in the loaded files. If not found then gives error